# How to find distance from a point to a set of points whose value is smallest?

Tags: geometry

I have a point say (1, 4) and a set of points, say, (4, 4), (2, 0) (8, 1).
I want to find distance from (1, 4) to the other three that has the smallest value. 
Brute force method is to calculate the euclidean distance from (1, 4) to each point and select the minimum.

All the points are not on a line.

I want to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

For these particular points:

It is clear that $(4,4)$ is exactly $3$ units away from $(1,4)$. And since the $y$ value of $(2,0)$ is already $4$ units away from the $y$ value of $(1,4)$, then that's the minimum distance between them: any difference in $x$-value can only increase that distance further.  Similarly, $(8,1)$ already has a difference of $7$ in $x$-value from $(1,4)$, so that distance is at least $7$. So, we can very quickly tell $(4,4)$ is the closest, without having to calculate all the exact distances.

In general, though, suppose your fixed point is $(x,y)$, and you have a bunch of other points $(x_i,y_i)$. Then for each of those other points you can calculate $dx_i^2+dy_i^2$ with $dx_i$ and $dy_i$ being the absolute difference in $x$ value and $y$ value respectively (i.e. $dx_i = |x-x_i|$ and $dy_i = |y-y_i|$) The point with the smallest value for this will be closest. There is no need to take the square root of this in order to calculate the actual distance, since if $x$ < $y$, then $\sqrt{x} < \sqrt{y}$. So at least you can avoid that step. Also, if you ever find that $dx_i \leq dx_j$ and $dy_i \leq dy_j$, then you immediately know that point $j$ is not any closer than point $i$.

Unfortunately, what does not work is to simply add $dx$ and $dy$ for each point and compare those. For example, if you have $dx_i=10$ and $dy_i=0$, while $dx_j=6$ and $dy_j=6$, then $dx_i+dy_i < dx_j+dy_j$, but $dx_i^2+dy_i^2 > dx_j^2+dy_j^2$